# Trying to build a jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dynamic, woocommerce, slider

Im trying to build a dynamic slider in WordPress using jquery to load a php array of dynamic gallery images, where i do not know beforehand how many images will be in the slider.

This is the code i wrote so far.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      //Slider
      $('.wp-post-image img').addClass('Slide'); //Add class to the gallery images
      $('.wp-post-image img').click(function() {
        var MyImageArray = <? wc_get_template('single-product/product-thumbnails.php');?>; 
        var focusImg = 1;   
        var imageHold = MyImageArray[focusImg];
        focusImg++;

        if(focusImg > 4) {//to be honest not sure about this number
            focusImg = 0;
        }
      });   
      $('.wp-post-image img').attr('src','imageHold');



      $('.Slide').css('position','absolute');

      $('#Slider_Arrow_Left').click(function() {
        $('.Slide').animate({'right':'+=500','easing':'swing'});
        $('.Slide').css('z-index','10000');

      });

      $('#Slider_Arrow_Right').click(function() {
        $('.Slide').animate({'left':'+=500','easing':'swing'}); 
        $('.Slide').css('z-index','10000');
      });

    }); //End jquery
</script>
```

As you can see, im trying to use the left and right arrow elements to slide the loaded images.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What seems to go wrong? It might help to build a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: my images don't load, much less slide.

Comment: What does `wc_get_template('single-product/product-thumbnails.php')` output? Or rather, what is the value of `MyImageArray`?

Comment: that  php code pulls the thumbnail page for woocommerce, getting the gallery images.

Comment: I'm curious about the actual value. I don't see where you're populating a slider with images.

Answer (score 0):

i would personally recommend you to try this https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html

it has so many properties by which you can achieve your requirements. I hope this would help you